# Show Index in Apache Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have Apache Phoenix 4.4 installed on HDP 2.3. Does anyone know how to view all indexes created on a table? Like MySQL has `show index on table_name` query. I couldn't find help on the documentation [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html).

Comment: can you please comment on why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are using sqlline, which is, by default, bundled with Phoenix, you should be able to see existing indices by issuing command

```
!indexes ${schema_name}.${table_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can view index and table data this way in case sqlline is not available:

SELECT * FROM "SYSTEM"."CATALOG" WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = '${SCHEMA_NAME}' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'i';